# Problems with C# lists, and ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, list, xna, outofrangeexception

I am in the process of making a farming/tower defense game and I am very new at programming. I seem to have a major problem with using Lists<> or arrays in XNA. I cannot get it to return the index that I want from the list.

The main question is inside my planting engine. I have successfully implemented a planting system that can generate a list of plants (spriteobjects) with varying properties and place them on the map. Now, I need a way to access a specific plant in the plant list based upon mouseclicking on that plant. I feel like I am very close, but I ended up with a ArgumentOutOfRangeException that I cannot solve. Here is a walkthrough of the code:

Initialization

```
 public void Addplants()
        {
            switch (Mode)
            {
            case "Wotalemon":
            NewPlant = new Plant(Texture, msRect);
            NewPlant.AddAnimation("seed", 0, 16, 64, 64, 1, 0.1f);
            NewPlant.AddAnimation("sprout", 64, 16, 64, 64, 1, 0.1f);
            NewPlant.AddAnimation("wota", 128, 16, 64, 64, 1, 1.0f);
            NewPlant.CurrentAnimation = "seed";
            NewPlant.DrawOffset = new Vector2(32, 48);
            NewPlant.Position = Position;
            NewPlant.Type = "wotalemon";
            NewPlant.Birthday = Days;
            NewPlant.IsSelected = false;
            plants.Add(NewPlant);
            thisPlant = NewPlant;
            //various plants after this
```

Update/Draw

I use some simple foreach loops to update and draw the plants, no problems here.

GetInfo (this method uses the spriteobject's hitbox property and a mouseRectangle)

```
public void GetInfo(Rectangle ms)
        {
            msRect = ms;
            for (int i = 0; i < plants.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (Plant NewPlant in plants)
                {
                    if (NewPlant.BoundingBox.Intersects(msRect))
                    {
                        SelectedIndex = i;
                        NewPlant.Tint = Color.Black;
                    }
                    else
                        NewPlant.Tint = Color.White;
                }

            }
        }
```

finally, here is the problem:

```
 public void SelectPlant()
        {
            //if (SelectedIndex != null)
            if (SelectedIndex > plants.Count | SelectedIndex < 0)
                SelectedIndex = plants.Count;
            SelectedPlant = plants[SelectedIndex];

        }
```

The exception is thrown in this line:

```
SelectedPlant = plants[SelectedIndex];
```

The debugger shows the value as 0. I have tried various methods to try to prevent the index from being null. I feel like something in the Getinfo() method is key here. I am convinced that I am very close to success because the color test that I have inserted in there works perfectly. When I mouseover a plant, it turns black, when I remove the mouse, it returns to normal.

This is EXACTLY the type of behavior I want except that I want it to **set selectedIndex to the index of the plant that I am mousing over**. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the if statement, `SelectedIndex = plants.Count;` should be `SelectedIndex = plants.Count-1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add this as a new answer since this is tackling a whole different issue. Taking a look at this code:

```
msRect = ms;
for (int i = 0; i < plants.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (Plant NewPlant in plants) // <-- this is redundant
    {
        if (NewPlant.BoundingBox.Intersects(msRect))
        {
            SelectedIndex = i;
            NewPlant.Tint = Color.Black;
        }
        else
            NewPlant.Tint = Color.White;
    }

}
```

You are looping through 'plants' twice inside each other! Once using an index (`for (int i = 0 ...`) and then inside that again using an iterator (`foreach (Plant NewPlant ...`).

Your options are to either change `GetInfo` to set the right index by using a single loop:

```
msRect = ms;
for (int i = 0; i < plants.Count; i++)
{
    Plant NewPlant = plants[i];
    if (NewPlant.BoundingBox.Intersects(msRect))
    {
        SelectedIndex = i;
        NewPlant.Tint = Color.Black;
    }
    else
        NewPlant.Tint = Color.White;
}
```

Or do the same thing and short circuit the need for SelectPlant() and SelectedIndex in the first place:

```
msRect = ms;
foreach (Plant NewPlant in plants) // no need for indexes
{
    if (NewPlant.BoundingBox.Intersects(msRect))
    {
        SelectedPlant = NewPlant; // this is everything you need
        NewPlant.Tint = Color.Black;
    }
    else
        NewPlant.Tint = Color.White;
}
```

You do however need to be careful using a 'global' variable like `SelectedPlant` to capture this logic. You're better off changing the whole `GetInfo` method to *return* the selected plant, rather than having it modify `SelectedPlant` directly. That is, change the method signature to return `Plant` not `void`, and change `SelectPlant = NewPlant` in the code above to `return NewPlant`. Or for even more fun as a single line:

```
return plants.Where(p => p.BoundingBox.Intersects(ms))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the very in-depth answer, bro. I didn't realize how inefficient my code was but I guess it's to be expected when you're new.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly make this a proper or `||` and check for `>= plants.Count` - remember that the list is indexed at `0`. Then as suggested set it to count - 1:

```
if (SelectedIndex >= plants.Count || SelectedIndex < 0)
    SelectedIndex = plants.Count - 1
```

Comment: @OP: make sure you want to set SelectedIndex to plans.Count - 1 _even when_ the original SelectedIndex < 0 (the alternative would be to set it to 0)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. But this still doesn't solve my main problem. GetInfo() method still does not return a dynamic plant index. It only returns the index for the last plant I planted. Anyone know of a good way to get list index from mousing over or clicking an object on the list?